# Delphi 10.4.2 - how to fix "The required attribute "Include" is missing from element <DesignClass>" error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I can't reproduce it, but I have gotten the above error message twice since upgrading to the new 10.4.2 community edition.  Once was when I upgraded a project from 10.3.3 CE, and another time was after I added a new VCL frame unit.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the IDE is adding a bogus empty **<DesignClass/>** line in the .dproj file.  Open the .dproj file in a text editor and removed the offending line from the **<ItemGroup>** section.

Proper DesignClass lines look like this: **<DesignClass>TFrame</DesignClass>** - do not remove them!

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with the parser in Delphi. Please write to Embarcadero support.

Comment: Good suggestion, however I have the CE edition which means no support!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error gave me ..."Include" in the  element"?
And I applied the search suggestion for Form, and there was a silly line.

I use Delphi 10.3

Comment: what silly line?